# null char in output yaml in yamldotnet serialization

Tags: c#, .net, yamldotnet

I'm trying to use YamlDotNet library to serialize a structure that may contains strings starting by a cariage return. When I serialize the data, I've got a strange output containing a null char.

```
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        var yaml = new YamlStream();
        var rootYamlNode = new YamlMappingNode();
        yaml.Add(new YamlDocument(rootYamlNode));

        rootYamlNode.Add("foo", "\nbar");
        yaml.Save(writer, false);
        Console.Write(writer.ToString());
        Console.Write(string.Join(", ", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writer.ToString()).Select(b => string.Format("{0:X2}", b)).ToArray()));
    }
```

render as :

```
foo: >2?-

  bar
...
66, 6F, 6F, 3A, 20, 3E, 32, 00, 2D, 0D, 0A, 0D, 0A, 20, 20, 62, 61, 72, 0D, 0A, 2E, 2E, 2E, 0D, 0A
```

With `?` beeing a null char.
(The hex sequence is the values of the bytes from the output encoded as UTF-8)

For information, I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with framework 3.5 (and yamldotnet version 3.8.0 which is the latest to date, but dotnetfiddle.net with framework 4.5 show the same problem with yamldotnet 3.8.0)

It look like a bug, but I've perhaps misused the api.

- Is there a bug somewhere in my code ?
- If it's a bug in yamldotnet, is there a way to workaround by asking yamldotnet to format the yaml using `"\nbar"` syntax instead of `>- ...`  syntax ?

As reference, here is a link to dotnetfiddle.net showing the problem : https://dotnetfiddle.net/jqVcL3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no answer, I'll provide my workaround to that bug instead of a proper answer to my own question.

I investigated further by reverse engineering YamlDotNet code. In the reversed sources, there is a file called `YamlDotNet\Core\Emitter.cs` containing a method `WriteBlockScalarHints`. Somewhere in that code, there is a reference to a pattern string `"{0}\0"`. From what I understand, The `\0` just make no sense, and the whole code would work correctly without it.

Given that, I looked for other occurrences of `\0` in the whole code, and found no other ones.

So I assume this `\0` is just a typo in the code.

As a workaround to make my code work, I just stripped every occurrence of `\0` from the output, and it just worked well.

Here is a link to a fork of the dotnetfiddle link I posted in the question with the workaround : https://dotnetfiddle.net/fRnZPS (Warning: this implementation is inefficient, and should not be used for large yaml)